# Evaluation accuracy stays the same while test accuracy increases just fine

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have tried over and over with different approaches to building this model however I continue to run into this issue where my training accuracy steadily increases just fine but my validation and evaluation accuracy remains very low (55% - 65%).

```
Epoch 95/100
119/119 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6326 - accuracy: 0.8057 - val_loss: 2.0461 - val_accuracy: 0.5985
Epoch 96/100
119/119 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6485 - accuracy: 0.7990 - val_loss: 1.9512 - val_accuracy: 0.5909
Epoch 97/100
119/119 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6263 - accuracy: 0.8032 - val_loss: 2.0344 - val_accuracy: 0.5682
Epoch 98/100
119/119 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6249 - accuracy: 0.7990 - val_loss: 2.0183 - val_accuracy: 0.5682
Epoch 99/100
119/119 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6189 - accuracy: 0.8007 - val_loss: 2.0818 - val_accuracy: 0.5758
Epoch 100/100
119/119 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6261 - accuracy: 0.8024 - val_loss: 2.0591 - val_accuracy: 0.5833
18/18 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 2.2385 - accuracy: 0.5628
EVAL:
[2.238506317138672, 0.5628318786621094]
```

The entire script is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical


def count_classes(y: list):
    counts = {}
    for i in y:
        if i in counts.keys():
            counts[i] += 1
        else:
            counts[i] = 1
    return counts

dataset = pd.read_csv('Dementia-data.csv')

X= dataset.iloc[:,1:]
y= dataset.iloc[:,0] # roughly 2562 input variables 

X.head(2)

#standardizing the input feature

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, shuffle = True, random_state = 0, test_size=0.2)

print("TRAIN:")
print(count_classes(list(y_train)))
print("TEST:")
print(count_classes(list(y_test)))

sc = StandardScaler()
scaler = sc.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.00005)

classifier = Sequential()
#First Hidden Layer
classifier.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.005), input_dim=2562))
#Second  Hidden Layer
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.005)))
#Output Layer
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))
classifier.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='random_normal'))

#Compiling the neural network
classifier.compile(optimizer =optimizer,loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics =['accuracy'])

#Fitting the data to the training dataset
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=200, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True)

eval_model=classifier.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("EVAL:")
print(eval_model)
```

I have tried all sorts of things to try to combat overfittings such as regulators, dropouts, and data splitting because that seems to be the lead cause for problems like this one. I do not know if I am missing something.

The class distribution for the test and train data is as follows, it doesn't look like there is any inconsistencies between the 2 datasets in terms of ratios of classses:

```
TRAIN:
{2: 822, 4: 136, 6: 229, 5: 184, 3: 76, 1: 57}
TEST:
{2: 199, 6: 59, 5: 45, 1: 26, 3: 15, 4: 33}
```

The plotted accuracy for training and testing:
[image: accuracy plotted]

The plotted loss for training and testing, the loss clearly increases for the testing data:
[image: loss plotted]

I have been struggling with this for weeks now and I'd truly appreciate any help to get this working. I have also tried using learning rates between 0.05 and 0.00005 with little to no improvement.

Comment: You have 2562 features? Why so many?

Comment: it is medical gene data for dementia research

Comment: Your model is able to memorize the class based on the features. Take a look at them, are all of them really meaningful and useful? Reduce the number of features, and/or reduce the number of the dense layer units

Comment: How would I go about reducing features?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Please try again by changing the learning_rate of the Adam optimizer to the default value (0.01).